# UIImageView as button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to make a UIImageView accept actions and fire them everytime it clicked on the UIImageVie, but i'm having hard time in getting it to work, please help me out

but here is what i'm doing:

```
[View setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

[View addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


- (void) myAction:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"It works!");
}
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**Objective-C**

In your `viewDidLoad:` method write this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0)];
    [imageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
    [imageview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap =  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapping:)];
    [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [imageview addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

    [self.view addSubview:imageview];
}
```

Then call your gesture method like this:

```
-(void)singleTapping:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"image clicked");
}
```

**Swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 100.0, y: 100.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0))
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image.png")
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let singleTap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.singleTapping(recognizer:)))
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)

    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
}

@objc func singleTapping(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    print("image clicked")
}
```

Comment: im trying it, but nothing happen... the consol dont print anything ( btw its for iphone )

Comment: Just fixed it, another code was blocking my app.. but thanks!

Comment: For Swift3: imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

Answer (score 12):

`UIImageView` is not a control, you can't add a target for **control** events to it. You have several options:

Place an invisible `UIButton` over the `UIImageView` and add your target to that. You can set the button's style to custom and its text (and image) to nothing to make it invisible.

Use just a `UIButton`. You can add a background image to it.

Add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your image view and implement it's touch handler method.

Subclass `UIImageView` and override the touch handling methods to do what ever you need to do.

Answer (score 8):

All you have to do is drag a Tap Gesture Recognizer onto the imageView (in Storyboard) and enable User Interaction on the Attributes Inspector.
If you want to use the image as a link to another view controller, just control-drag the Tap Gesture Recognizer icon in the bottom of the view controller to the destination view controller.

Answer (score 1):

`UIImageView` is not a `UIControl` so it doesn't have the `addTarget:action:forControlEvents` method as part of its interface. You can use a gesture recognizer instead.

Comment: It says: class 'MainViewController' does not implement the 'UIGestureRecognizerDelegate' protocol, what should i do?

Comment: Add The UITapGestureRecognizerDelegate to your class (I usually put it the .h file interface, but you can also do it in the .m interface declaration)

Answer (score 1):

i am not a pro but you can use button for this

```
UIButton *imageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
imageButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
[imageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Your_Image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
imageButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
[imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:imageButton];
```