# How to make image view as button in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uitouch, uievent

For example:
Collection view have four images,The user touches any cell mean its want to go to another view controller.give some idea for me friends.
 [image]

Take this image as example if the user click the chrome image means it go to another view controller.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIImageView as button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330544/uiimageview-as-button)

Comment: i think we can use uitouch class for this.

Answer (score 2):

Create new `UIButton`, then use `setImage` method on it to set the image. Leave the title empty.

Comment: is there any possible to use touch up inside method for uiimage view

Answer (score 0):

use this code for objc:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0)];
[imageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
[imageview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap =  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapping:)];
[singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[imageview addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

[self.view addSubview:imageview];
}
```